# Ruby on Rails: Error when running a rake task from initializer file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, initializer

I have the file config/initializers/custom.rb

In the file, there is only one line:

```
`rake thinking_sphinx:start`
```

I thought this was supposed to just execute the line like when typing it from a command line.  With this line of code, when I run "ruby script/server", the server freezes and outputs no error messages.  Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initializers load when your application loads. Rake tasks generally load your application. If you call a Rake task from an initializer, you're going to throw your app for a loop.

If you're worried about forgetting to start Sphinx in development, just give yourself a little warning:

```
# config/initializers/custom.rb
begin
  ThinkingSphinx::Search.search "test" # test search
rescue ThinkingSphinx::ConnectionError
  puts "** Oops! ThinkingSphinx is off! **"
end
```

Comment: eh...i like the idea, but stil buggy

/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/lib/thinking_sphinx/collection.rb:100:in `class_from_crc': You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! (NoMethodError)
The error occurred while evaluating nil.constantize     from /vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/lib/thinking_sphinx/collection.rb:79:in `instances_from_classes

Comment: Try changing from a blank search to "test" (blank searches have worked for me in the past when calling ModelName.search, but I guess things blow up when they're not scoped).

Comment: this works.  i like this method too because i should probably be using a daemon manager plugin to manage the actual starting and stopping of daemons in production, but it is very nice to have a warning shoot off in dev mode. especially until i get around to setting up the daemon manager

Answer (score 0):

I asked about how to get it to start up in dev mode via netbeans but the idea is the same.  [Bounty is still open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730003/netbeans-and-rails-is-there-a-way-to-make-the-run-option-in-netbeans-also-start).

My guess is that your not getting to the server starting because sphinx needs it's own process so it never returns to your custom initializer.

Comment: i thought about that as well, except when i run the rake task from the command line, the process is started in the background.  so this should not be occuring